# draw canvas from c++-code

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a canvas (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html) in my qml-file. 
I made a class "Backend" in c++ and added it in main.cpp with `qmlRegisterType<Backend>("de.xxx.backend", 1, 0, "Backend");` and then I imported this class in main.qml with `import de.xxx.backend 1.0` and added an instance of it.

Now I want to draw on this canvas from my c++ code. I want a function in my class Backend with name "draw()" and in this function I can use functions like drawRect() or similar. Is this possible? How can I do that?

thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Drawing on a QML `Canvas` from C++ is the worst idea I've heard in a while.

For starters - it gains you nothing.

Second - there is really no public C++ API for the canvas, and using the private one is an extremely bad idea.

Finally - if you well about drawing from C++ that much, just implement a `QQuickPaintedItem` which is a QML element you draw using the C++ `QPainter` API.